# Under what conditions is the product of two Bisymmetric Matrices Bisymmetric?

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be bisymmetric matrices (reflectional symmetry around both main diagonals).

**Under what conditions is the product $AB$ also bisymmetric?**

Is it sufficient/necessary that $A$ and $B$ commute?

Answer (score 1):

For symmetric matrices $A$, $B$ to have $AB$ symmetric it is necessary
and sufficient that they commute. Since
$$(AB)^t=B^tA^t=BA$$
$$AB=(AB)^t$$ iff $AB=BA$.

In addition for the symmetric matrix $A$ to be bisymmetric, we need
$JAJ=A$ where $J$ is the identity matrix reflected about the central
vertical axis. Then $J^2=I$. So if $A$ and $B$ are bisymmetric and commute,
then
$$AB=JAJJBJ=JABJ$$
so that $AB$ is also bisymmetric.

Comment: Haven't you shown that $AB = JABJ$ regardless of whether $A$ and $B$ commute? So commutativity is only required to preserve symmetry about the main diagonal?

Comment: Yes.  A product of centrosymmetric matrices is always centrosymmetric.  Bisymmetry merely tacks on the additional condition of symmetry.